# Неправильная работа скрипта БЕЗ обновления страницы

Tags: php, jquery

Функция:

```html
<script>
function clearLogs() {
 if (confirm("Вы уверены, что хотите удалить логи сервера?")) {
  <?php if($server['server_status'] == 1): ?>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['btnClear'])){
  unlink("путь к файлу");}
  ?>
  $.jGrowl("Логи успешно удалены!", { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-green" });
  //setTimeout("redirect('/servers/serverLogs/index/<?php echo $server['server_id'] ?>')", 1500);
  <?php elseif($server['server_status'] == 2): ?>
  $.jGrowl("Логи нельзя удалить на включенном сервере!", { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-red" });
  <?php elseif($server['server_status'] == 0): ?>
  $.jGrowl("11111", { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-red" });
  <?php elseif($server['server_status'] == 4): ?>
  $.jGrowl("22222", { sticky: !1, position: "top-right", theme: "bg-red" });
  <?php endif; ?>
  return false;
 } else {
  return false;
 }
}
</script>
```

Если функцию выше вызывать таким способом:

```html
<form method='post'>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnClear" id="btnClear" onclick="clearLogs();">Очистить лог</button>
</form>
```

То, удаление логов работает, **НО** перезагружается страница автоматически.

Если вызывать таким способом:

```html
<form method='post'>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnClear" id="btnClear" onclick="return clearLogs();">Очистить лог</button>
</form>
```

Страница не обновляется, но логи не удаляет!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело.

Добавлено:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так очистку лога не на submit вешайте, а просто кнопку input type="button", или отменяйте действие submit -  preventDefault()

Comment: @Jean-Claude, что-то не пойму. Сделал так: <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnClear" id="btnClear" onclick="clearLogs();" value="Очистить лог">
Ничего не изменилось, может я не правильно понял тебя?

Comment: на input type="submit" страница перегружается, надо отменять это стандартное действие браузера методом события preventDefault() https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action либо убрать на просто кнопку  input type="button"

Comment: @Максим, у вас условия, генерирующие js код генерируются на сервере. Вам нужно сделать `html` без `php`, которая отправляет `ajax запрос` к `php`, который в свою очередь отдаст `json` ответ.

Answer (score 2):

А зачем вам для этого вообще форма? Можно ведь на любой элемент повесить событие. Например так:

```js
function clearLogs() {
  console.log('clearLogs');
  // code
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span class="btn btn-danger" onclick="clearLogs()">Очистить лог</span>
```

Либо нужно запретить действие браузера по умолчанию с помощью вызова метода [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('clearLogs');
  // code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form method='post'>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnClear" id="btnClear">Очистить лог</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Я похоже туплю нереально, но вместо // code что должно быть? У меня ведь clearLogs отдельная функция. Я только учусь.. :)

Comment: Если нужно было перенести код из функции clearLogs туда, где // code, то я так делал, ничего не изменилось, лог не удаляется.

Comment: @Максим так php выполнять нужно на сервере, а у вас js выполняется в браузере. Вам нужно основы изучать, а потом уже вопросы задачать. Книжки почитайте, видеокурсы рекомендую

Comment: спасибо за рекомендации, за код, но решил проблему куда проще. В form добавил условие (вкл/выкл) и каждому условию - свою кнопку. На выкл поставил span. В общем, результат тот, который и нужен был. Большое спасибо тем кто помогал!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#clearLogs').submit(clearlogs);

function clearLogs(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (confirm("Вы уверены, что хотите удалить логи сервера?")) {
    $.post("clearlogs.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      $.jGrowl(data, {
        sticky: !1,
        position: "top-right",
        theme: "bg-red"
      });
    });
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form method="post" id="clearlogs">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="btnClear" id="btnClear">Очистить лог</button>
</form>
```

clearlogs.php:

```
<?php 
if($server['server_status'] == 1) {
    if(isset($_POST['btnClear'])){
        unlink("путь к файлу");
    }
    echo "Логи успешно удалены!";
} elseif ($server['server_status'] == 2) {
    echo "Логи нельзя удалить на включенном сервере!";
} ...
?>
```

Comment: Не работает, даже confirm не срабатывает, при нажатии на кнопку просто обновляет страницу и всё. Файл clearlogs.php лежит где и serverLogs.php
Скрины кода на всякий случай прикрепил в 1-ый пост, всё же правильно сделал?

Comment: посмотрите что в консоли пишет, если windows - f12

Comment: никаких ошибок нет.